# Find in which domain value is located

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array like this

```
x = [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

is there a built function in numpy that can get me in which domain my value is ?

Domain is defined as *`i`* if

```
    x[i,1]<= value <x[i,2].
```

For example :

```
np.find(3.5,x)
```

return 
3 (index of the domain ) ? 
If there isn't can anyone suggest the best way (performance wise) to do such a task ?

Comment: Please check whether my edit (definition of domain) is correct.

Comment: Is it always the case that `x[i+i, 0] == x[i, 1]`?

Comment: @roadrunner66 yes it is correct

Comment: @ali_m yes it's always the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the edge values for consecutive "domains" always match up exactly (i.e. if `x[i+i, 0] == x[i, 1]`) then you don't really need both columns - you could just use [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with the second column:

```
edges = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
x = 0.5, 2.9, 3.8
idx = np.digitize(x, bins=edges[:, 1])

print(edges[idx])
# [[0 1]
#  [2 3]
#  [3 4]]
```

This assumes that the values in `edges[:, 1]` are monotonically increasing. If they aren't then you could use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get the indices that will sort them in ascending order, then pass these as the `sorter=` argument to `searchsorted`. Values that are "out-of-bounds" will be handled like this:

```
print(edges[:, 1].searchsorted(-1))   # smaller than edges[0, 1]
# 0

print(edges[:, 1].searchsorted(10))   # larger than edges[-1, 1]
# 4
```